# Upgrading Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, ssl, openssl

I'm on a Windows Server 2008 r2 machine that functions as an internal web server using Apache, PHP and MySQL.

Through some searching, I came across a post that claimed to be successful in "upgrading" Apache from a no_ssl version to the open_ssl version. However, when I attempted the install, it failed, saying another version of the product was already install and that I would have to uninstall it.

I do not wish to uninstall Apache as I do not want to lose any of the configuration settings that I currently have in place.

Is there anyway to "upgrade" my Apache and enable SSL?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some more searching and asking around in other forums, this turned out to be a lot more stress free than originally thought.

Simply use Control Panel to uninstall Apache. You htdocs and conf folders WILL NOT be removed and you can then install the openssl version of Apache and everything will run without any configuring.

I would, of course, backup your htdocs and conf folders before hand, just in case.

Also, I did not enable SSL yet, this was simply uninstall Apache no-ssl and reinstall Apache with openssl... the whole process took 3 minutes and the sites that were hosted came back up immediately.